# Solving non linear ODE numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to solve the following eqation numerically"
$ mx''+kx = f(x,\dot{x},t)$

The funciton $f(x,\dot{x},t)$ and is the assumed to be an external load, it changes every time step and is assumed to have the form: $f(x,\dot{x},t) \approx C1x + C2 \dot{x} $. Which allows for rewriting:

$ mx''+kx = \frac{df}{dx}x + \frac{df}{d\dot{x}}\dot{x} $

I tried solving the equation by use of a Runge Kutta scheme, and discretized the differentials by using data from the previous timestep. But it explodes after a few time steps.

I hoped one of you had a suggestios...

Comment: If $C_1 > 0$ or $C_2 > 0$ the solution grows without limit.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of that exploding behavior? If $C_1, C_2$ are negative, the system is an oscillation with frequency $\sqrt{k+|C_1|}$ and friction that continuously removes energy so that the solution collapses to the origin. This should also hold under numerical integration. If that is not the case, please also post the Runge-Kutta code to verify that it is error-free.